# autohotkey addition leaving preceding 0 intact

Tags: autohotkey

I am relearning AHK right now and I've come with a problem that I can't seem to figure out.

On my form I have a text box, which by default is set as: 0000

When I hit my 'start' button, I need to add 1 to this through every iteration of my loop..

IE:  0001, 0002, 0003, 0004, etc..

I've tried searching google to see if there is an answer, to no avail.  Everything I've got so far removes the preceding 0's.

```
guiControlGet, txtLst,, last

tot := %txtLst%+1
```

I have also tried:  `tot := 1+%txtLst%` and something like: `tot := 0001 + %txtLst%` all to no avail.

Any ideas of suggestions welcome.  I'll try anything reallyl.

Comment: I added another example in case you simply want three zeroes in font at all times.

Comment: Within an expression variables are not surrounded by `%`s. Anything after a `:=` is interpreted as an expression.

Answer (score 1):

You are treating 0000 as an integer. There is no such integer `0001`.
You would need to do floating-point addition.
Here is a test example using a timer:

```
number := 0000

SetTimer, Add, 1000

Add:
number += 0.0001
StringTrimLeft, temp, number, 2
StringTrimRight, OutputVar, temp, 2 
traytip,, %OutputVar%
Return
```

`number += 0.0001` would produce `0.000100` the first time the timer calls `Add`.
`StringTrimLeft` and `StringTrimRight` can be used to remove the first and last 2 characters.

If for some reason you want three zeros in front at all times:

```
number := 0000

SetTimer, Add, 1000

Add:
number += 1
OutputVar := 000 number
traytip,, %OutputVar%
Return
```

Manual references:
[SetTimer](http://l.autohotkey.net/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm)
[+=](http://l.autohotkey.net/docs/Variables.htm#Operators)
[StringTimLeft](http://l.autohotkey.net/docs/commands/StringTrimLeft.htm)
[StringTrimRight](http://l.autohotkey.net/docs/commands/StringTrimLeft.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this...

```
ProcessCounter := 1
Processed = % Edit Point . SubStr("0000"ProcessCounter, -3)
msgbox, %Processed%
```